# Eye Tracking for Unity3d

Tags: opencv, mobile, camera, eye-tracking

How could I go about implementing eye tracking in a Unity3D mobile project without external hardware for standalone machines?

Answer (score 1):

Eye-tracking based on a webcam is, from my experience, terrible.

No software that I've found, that required only a standard webcam, has worked better than a simple "move mouse slowly downward when I'm looking down". This is simply because there's not enough data to interpret into angles precise enough to calculate a screen position.

That said, Pygaze is free and open source and can work with webcams, and python can be interfaced with unity. There are some tools out there, but you might end up just working with sockets between the two.

If you accept the use of hardware, I know tobii provides a unity sdk. There are also cheaper alternatives, that work with pygaze.

Comment: Beware the EyeTracker 5 doesn't support WIndows Eye-Tracking (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/extended-eye-tracking-unity), but the older and not-for-sale 4c does (at this time anyway.) Tobii is oddly focused on licensing too. Both are also limed in the screen size they support. They do provide a Unity SDK that works at an object level (not an acurate pose in real-time.) They DO provide head-tracking (like TrackIR) as well though which leaves some interesting possibilities.